# How to move the by straight rather than in an angle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am developing a game where there are enemies and  cars.So currently my cars move towards the enemies in a diagonal shape they hit them and earn points.Now I want to make the hero to make the move in a straight manner(like snake game no diagonal movement) and then hit the enemy and gain points.

So my current way of hitting the enemy is like

```
function angleBetweenTwoPoints(p1, p2) {
    return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
  }
function degreeToRadian(degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
  }
var angle = angleBetweenTwoPoints(this.target.position, this.position);
      var cos = Math.cos(degreeToRadian(angle)) * -1;
      var sin = Math.sin(degreeToRadian(angle));
      this.angle = angle;
      this.position.x += cos * this.speed;
      this.position.y -= sin * this.speed;
      if (distance(this.position, this.target.position) < 10) {
        this.target.position.x = Math.random() * mainCanvas.width;
        this.target.position.y = Math.random() * mainCanvas.height;
        this.hitCount++;
        console.log("Hit!");
        ctx.fillText("points : " + hitCount, 32, 32);


      }
```

So now I want to make the car move by not diagonally and in a straight manner.

This is my working  [game](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/).Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can not haz teh codez.

Comment: No I am asking for not code I want the idea to move the car.I am looking into the a star path finding algorithm and seeing how to integrate it

Comment: you have to make each cars distinct then apply an individual comportement, when it hit the target, increase the angle step by step when changing with an inertia, and i think you would have sth good..
Or use pixi.js and tweenlite (GSAP) before dying xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Pixi : http://www.pixijs.com/
And GSAP : https://greensock.com/

You will find easily everything to do it better ;)

Comment: Don't i need a path finding algorithm?

Comment: Gsap can be used by itself, start to learn it now, it simple as hell (like jquery animate but really better)